# Preventing lambdas from being stepped into when hosting method is DebuggerHidden

Tags: c#

```
private static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetRandomInteger());
    Console.ReadLine();
}

[DebuggerHidden]
private static int GetRandomInteger()
{
    Func<int> random = () => 4;
    return GetRandomInteger(random);
}

[DebuggerHidden]
private static int GetRandomInteger(Func<int> random)
{
    return random();
}
```

Using the code above, is there a way to prevent the `Func<int> random = () => 4;` line from getting stepped into when debugging?

Comment: You could edit the IL to apply the `[DebuggerHidden]` attribute to the function that's generated for the anonymous method, but I don't think there's a way to do this directly from C#. (And in general, if you're accepting arbitrary `Func<int>`s, the debugger will step into them based on whether or not they have the attribute. In other words, the attribute isn't recursive.)

Comment: This is an unsolvable problem for lamdas.  Ideally the C# compiler would propagate the attribute to the hidden class that implements the lambda.  But it doesn't do so and the team has been aware of the problem.  They surely don't like implementing it, choosing which attributes to propagate is a slippery slope.  Keep Debug.StepOut handy, as always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you could use a private function with the `[DebuggerHidden]` attribute instead of a labmda, and set the `Func<int>` delegate to the private function.

Comment: What should I do when I can not rewrite lambda to private method?

Comment: There isn't another workaround (besides the property workaround below). What's stopping you from being able to rewrite the method?

Comment: BTW: In case you're wondering if the new 'local methods' will help out it doesn't look like you can apply attributes to them

Comment: Also note that Visual Studio has intellisense that will rewrite the lamba as a private method for you - which can save some messing around for complex signatures. As of current version you have to select 'Introduce Local' and then 'Use local function' and then 'Convert to method.

Comment: After a few more years of experience, a case that comes up is anonymous classes can't be moved to a method signature. I think the new tuples can help here, but I haven't used that in practice.

Answer (score 2):

`[DebuggerHidden]` can be used on a property, and this property appears to behave as you would like:

```
[DebuggerHidden]
private static Func<int> random
{
  get { return () => 4; }
}
```

It is a workaround, like the other answer; however, it keeps the lambda and may be closer to the original intent.