# DebuggerHiddenAttribute doesn't work with lambda

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-debugging

There is the next code:

```
Func(); // I want debugger to highlight this line when exception is happened within Func.

[DebuggerHidden] // or [DebuggerNonUserCode]
private static void Func() {
   Action act = () => throw new Exception(); // But debugger highlights this line.
   act();
}
```

Two questions: why and how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing lambdas from being stepped into when hosting method is DebuggerHidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655590/preventing-lambdas-from-being-stepped-into-when-hosting-method-is-debuggerhidden)

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue based on the another thread? If not, update your question with your test result, if you have resolved it, you can delete it or approve the dup request, thanks.

Comment: Answers in that issue: replace lambda with private method. It's not problem solving. And I can't replace my lambda. So, I didn't resolve it.

Comment: Maybe my issue is duplicate. But that issue hasn't good answer, that issue is a little different. and name of my issue is simpler.